# How to restrict software distribution or make sure it should not be copied

Tags: software, drm

I Want to release software and it is going to be hosted on the client system. How to make sure that it should not be copied or how to restrict unpaid users using the software.

I have 2 questions.

1. What are the different options to implement?
2. What are the different aspects of security to be considered?

Note: This application is hosted on a local system although it is browser-based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect an offline proprietary software from being stolen](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150974/how-to-protect-an-offline-proprietary-software-from-being-stolen), [Can I use hardware token OTP to stop piracy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26559/can-i-use-hardware-token-otp-to-stop-piracy).

Comment: tl;dr of the dupes: No matter what you do, it will be bypassable, and it will annoy your legitimate users.